# Sitecore Powershell script to add items in array

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am a Sitecore PowerShell newbie.

I have to write a Sitecore PowerShell script to ignore certain items from consideration based on their template types.

For this we can add these items to an array and use `-notin` for comparison.

Below is a code sample:

```
#ignored items list start
$nodeFolderTemplate = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/System/Node" 
$layoutFolderTemplate = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Layout Folder" 
$rederingFolderTemplate = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Renderings/Rendering Folder"
$commonFolderTemplate = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/Common/Folder"
$placeHolderSettingsFolder = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Placeholder Settings Folder"
$branchFolderTemplate = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/System/Branches/Branch Folder"
$template = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template"
$dictionaryDomain = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/System/Dictionary/Dictionary Domain"
$dictionaryEntry = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/System/Dictionary/Dictionary entry"
$ignoredFolders = @( $nodeFolderTemplate.ID, $layoutFolderTemplate.ID, $rederingFolderTemplate.ID, $commonFolderTemplate.ID, $placeHolderSettingsFolder.ID, $branchFolderTemplate.ID )
$ignoredItems = @( $dictionaryDomain.ID, $ignoredFolders.ID, $commonFolderTemplate.ID)
#ignored items list end 

 $items = Get-ChildItem $selectedValues.SelectedFolderPath -Recurse | 
              Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -notin $ignoredFolders }
```

Can anybody please suggest a better way to do it?

Comment: And what is wrong with your current script?

Comment: She wants to know if there's an alternate approach to this.

Comment: It is working fine. But is there any better way than this?

Comment: If that's a one time execution script and you don't plan to run it frequently, it's all good. If you want to execute it quite often in the future, you may think about improving performance a bit - e.g. check if removing -Recurse from the script and excluding some folders template early, then running get-children non recursively on the next level wouldn't be faster.

Comment: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/training Check this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue I see with your script is that you are creating a variable for each template type. If you have a big list of templates then it would be difficult to manage the script.

So, Instead of creating a variable for each template path you can use an array for template paths.

**Example** -

```
$templatePaths  =     "/sitecore/templates/System/Node",
                      "/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Layout Folder",
                      "/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Renderings/Rendering Folder"

$templateIds = @()
$templatePaths | ForEach-Object -Process { $templateIds += (Get-Item $_ ).ID }

$items = Get-ChildItem $selectedValues -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -notin $templateIds }
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the thing I was looking for.